# Exceptions over remote methods

Tags: language-agnostic, exception, rmi

What are the best practices for exceptions over remote methods?

I'm sure that you need to handle all exceptions at the level of a remote method implementation, because you need to log it on the server side. But what should you do afterwards?

Should you wrap the exception in a RemoteException (java) and throw it to the client? This would mean that the client would have to import all exceptions that could be thrown. Would it be better to throw a new custom exception with fewer details? Because the client won't need to know all the details of what went wrong. What should you log on the client? I've even heard of using return codes(for efficiency maybe?) to tell the caller about what happened.

The important thing to keep in mind, is that the client **must** be informed of what went wrong. A generic answer of "Something failed" or no notification at all is unacceptable. And what about runtime (unchecked) exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did. Every Remote Method implementation catches all Exceptions on the server side and logs them. Then they are wrapped in a Custom Exception, which will contain a description of the problem. This description must be useful to the **client**, so it won't contain all the details of the caught Exception, because the client doesn't need them. They have already been logged on the server side. Now, on the client, these Exceptions can be handled how the user wishes.

Why I chose using Exceptions and not return codes is because of one very important drawback of return codes: you can't throw them to higher levels without some effort. This means you have to check for an error right after the call and handle it there. But this may not be what I want.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want to be able to differentiate if the failure was due to a system failure (e.g. a service or machine is down) or a business logic failure (e.g. the user does not exist).

I'd recommend wrapping all system exceptions from the RMI call with your own custom exception. You can still maintain the information in the exception by passing it to your custom exception as the cause (this is possible in Java, not sure about other languages). That way client only need to know how to handle the one exception in the cause of system failure. Whether this custom exception is checked or runtime is up for debate (probably depends on your project standards). I would definitely log this type of failure.

Business type failures can be represented as either a separate exception or some type of default (or null) response object. I would attempt to recover (i.e. take some alternative action) from this type of failure and log only if the recovery fails.

Answer (score 0):

In past projects we'd catch all service layer (tier) exceptions at the very top of the layer, passing the application specific error codes/information to the UI via DTO's/VO's.  It's a simple approach in that there's an established pattern of all error handling happening in the same place for each service instead of scattered about the service and UI layers.

Then all the UI has to do is inspect the DTO/VO for a flag (hasError?) and display the error message(s), it doesn't have to know nor care what the actual exception was.

Answer (score 0):

I would always log the exception within my application (at the server side as defined in your question).

I would then throw an exception, to be caught by the client. If the caller could take corrective action to prevent the exception then I would ensure that the exception contained this information (e.g. `DateTime argName must not be in the past`). If the error was caused by some outage of a third party system then I might pass this information up the call stack to the caller.

If, however, the exception was essentially caused by a bug in my system then I would structure my exception handling such that a non-informative exception message (e.g. `General failure`) was used.